# Cancelling Remaining AssetExports

Tags: swift, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to allow a user to cancel the exporting of a series of videos, while in the middle exporting (Goal: cancel the remaining unexpected videos).

Code for button:

```
var cancelExportButton = UIButton()

cancelExportButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelExport(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func cancelExport(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("export cancelled")
//cancel remaining exports code 
    }
```

```
for i in 0...videoURLs.count - 1 {
            overlayVideo(titleImage: titleImage, captionImage: captionImage, videoURL: videoURLs[i])

}


func overlayVideo(titleImage: UIImage, captionImage: UIImage, videoURL: URL) {

//...composition and mixing code, not important to exporting

       // Exporting
          let number = Int.random(in: 0...99999)
          let savePathUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/\(number).mp4")
                do { // delete old video
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl)
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }


                let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
                assetExport.videoComposition = layerComposition
                assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
                assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
                assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

      assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
                    switch assetExport.status {
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                        print("success")
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                        print("failed \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                        print("cancelled \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
                    default:
                        print("complete")

                    }
                }
    }
```

What code (using queues or monitoring properties) would work in `cancelExport` to cancel all  remaining function instances/unexported assets?

I've tried turning `assetExport` into a class variable and setting it nil after successful exports, but exports are being done at the same time so it messes up.

Comment: Where is the "series" of videos in your code? I only see one function that exports one video.

Comment: edited to show for loop containing ```overlayVideo()```

Comment: Ah. You can't cancel them the way you're doing it. You have them configured to start all at the same time, and there is no access to the process until it is finished. You would need to line them up so that each cannot even start until the previous one has finished. That way, to cancel, you simply never start in the first place.